# How to implement LazyLoad on TabbedPage MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a MAUI project that uses TabbedPage with Shell, it is working fine, but since my app has 4 tabs and all of them are making api calls, the app takes up to 25 seconds to load completely. Is there a way to only load the pagges until they are selected?

Here is my code (It only has 2 tabs but the other 2 are the same:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="NewScholarApp.Views.HomePage"
          xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NewScholarApp.ViewModels"
   Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
   Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="#00928A"
   BackgroundColor="#00928A"
         Title="HomePage">

<TabBar Route="Home">
    <Tab Title="Mensajes" Icon="messages_icon.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MessagesPage}"/>
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Documentos" Icon="documents_icon.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:DocumentsPage}"/>
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

With Xamarin.Forms, I used Prism, it has a built-in interface to detect when a tab is selected. On MAUI, I am using Community Toolkit MVVM nuget so I'm looking for an alternative to achieve this.

Comment: Not exactly lazy loading, but consider making the API calls themselves in a background task - use `Task.Run` - get data into local variables but don't set UI properties yet. Then when you have all the data, use `Dispatcher.Dispatch` to run UI code (that is allowed to set UI properties). Search for info about those two features, if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature request tracked in [Enhancement Shell TabBar Action on Current Tab Tapped #6544](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6544). There is something like a command property `OnCurrentTabTapped` for each tab to detect when a tab is selected. You can follow up there or create a [new one](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose) on Github.

As an alternative workaround, if you are only using [TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0) without `Shell`, you can manage to override the method `OnCurrentPageChanged` that call on tab change to detect which tab is selected and then loaded the corresponding page.

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppTabPage.MyTabbedPage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiAppTabPage.Views"
             Title="MyTabbedPage">
    
    <pages:MessagePage x:Name="Message"></pages:MessagePage>
    <pages:DocumentsPage x:Name="Document"></pages:DocumentsPage>
  
</TabbedPage>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged() 
{
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();


        if(CurrentPage is MessagePage)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MessagePage");
            //detect the tab is selected and load the page
        }

        else if (CurrentPage is DocumentsPage)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DocumentsPage");
            //detect the tab is selected and load the page
        }
}
```

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here. We can work together to figure it.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Shell in my app so I am looking for a workaround or a plugin to help me to that. I think that Sharpnado.Tabs and DelayedView would help, I am currently trying to implement Sharpnado.Tabs but I am having some issues.